# Return values ​that are between a tag

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a text in a textbox, and I would like to return all the values ​​of that text that are between the tag below:

```
<span _ngcontent-c6="">
```

Ex:

```
<span _ngcontent-c6="">1</span>
<span _ngcontent-c6="">2</span>
<span _ngcontent-c6="">3</span>
<span _ngcontent-c6="">4</span>
<span _ngcontent-c6="">5</span>
```

The return would be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat it as XML, e.g. this simple console app gives the output you state:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim x As XElement = <xml>
                                <span _ngcontent-c6="">1</span>
                                <span _ngcontent-c6="">2</span>
                                <span _ngcontent-c6="">3</span>
                                <span _ngcontent-c6="">4</span>
                                <span _ngcontent-c6="">5</span>
                            </xml>

        Dim a = x.<span>.Select(Function(b) b.Value)

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, a))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```